# SQL Server database security. Attaching database from one instance to other

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I installed sql server 2005 Express in a virtual clean Windows xp machine.

On the database engine I created two instances, each one of these I have configured mixed authentication and the first user 'sa' password is 'password1' and the second 'password2'.

Then in the first instance, I have created a new database with a common table and a few details. Followed by this stopped the first instance I try to attach the database in the second instance. As it was to be expected, this caused an error and the process was aborted.

Then what I did was to change the password for the 'sa' user and I put the same one that was in the one instance ('passowrd1'). Now try to attach the database, the process is run correctly and the database created in the first instance was properly attached in the second instance.

Until here nothing weird, my surprise was given to make the next step.
In the second instance, I have again changed the password to the user 'sa' and this time put it as it was originally ('password2') and the attached database is kept running.

This is the first thing that I don't understand why it occurs in this way. And as last test, I stopped the second instance and start the first, and to my surprise the database also kept running.

Can someone tell me why this behavior is given as well?

My fear is to create a database with a password 'X' and then for some reason someone discover the password and then changing it, if someone attached database in another instance, can use the old password to open it. The same behavior is happening at others editions of sql server?

Are there any security layer extra that recommend me to apply?

Comment: This is an interesting experiment.  I think I understand the steps you took, but I'm unclear on a few things.  Any chance you could script out the exercise so we can see the exact steps?

Comment: Do you mean the SQL script of the steps I do? I'm not sure that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

The SA password should have no effect on any user-created databases.  It only would affect system databases (Master, Model, MSDB, TempDb).  Unless, of course, you encrypted your database files or if you are doing a password-secured backup/restore (which, you are not).

When you were unable to attach the first time, I would suspect that the first SQL instance had not finished shutting down yet.  It was merely a coincidence that you took a few minutes to change passwords and then were able to attach the original DB file.

If you want to secure your databases, so they are not stolen and attached to another database, I would recommend doing this at the Server OS level.  Prevent people from getting to the file in the first place.

Comment: I can not prevent access to the .mdf file already that the database is on a server of the customer. The only thing to which they have no access is the instance where the database runs, but the problem is that attaching the .mdf in another instance the client can access this without problems